# How can I isolate css for part of a page?

Tags: css, html, iframe

The easy "HTML5" way would be:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Hello world!</p>"></iframe>
```

Here's more info on that: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp

But this is not supported in any of the modern browsers.  Any suggestions on an alternative way to make this work?

[edit] Sorry for lack of clarity.  My goal is to open a 3rd party web site using its own css in a frame (or other element) of a page.  I have my own css that governs my content, but I'd like to have the 3rd party site also rendered correctly with its own css and not have the 2 interfere with each other.

Comment: Your question does not say anything about css, but the heading says that the issue is isolating css. How to make “this” work is not a real question when it relates to an unsupported construct in a draft.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, "isolating" would refer to restricting a subset of styles to only apply to some content on a given page.

I would generally avoid using an `iframe` (or rather a more compliant `<object>`)  unless that is the only way to integrate third-party content, even though it would in fact limit the applicable scope of any applied css.

Parent selectors would likely be appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish, acting effectively as a "pseudo-namespace" for your rules:

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
<p>Some great content here!</p>
<div id="isolated-content"><p>Hello world styled differently!</p></div>
```

and

```
p {color:black;}
#isolated-content p {color:red;}
```

Would only apply red color to the second "Hello world" paragraph.

Naturally, all normal css mechanics still applies (inheritance, cascading etc.) so you may have to override the rules accordingly. Unless you provide specific scenario details, this is the most details I can offer.